# Execution order inside a while-loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to implement the quick sort algorithm - it contains a while loop with a couple of if-statements inside. It got me wondering about the order of execution inside while loops. In the following case:

```
let target = 100;
let str1 = '###';
let str2 = '$$$';

while(i < target) {
  if(str1.length < 10) {
    str1 += '#'
  }
  if(str2.length < 10) {
    str2 += '$'
  }
  i++
}
```

Does it keep executing `str1 += '#'` until `str1.length === 10`, or does it run once then move on to check `if(str2.length < 10)`, then `i++`, and *only then* going back to `if(str1.length ...)`?

Comment: the whole code inside while is run once in each iteration - put a `console.log(i, str1, str2)` at the bottom of that loop and you'll see

Comment: It does what you have suggested as the second option. I.E. adds '#', then adds '$' then `i++` before beginning at the top of the loop again. More or less js is 'top to bottom'.